# How can I relay to the user that there is a max number of profiles available?

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, user-behavior, ux-field

So I currently have a list of profiles where the user can click a button to add more profiles if they wish. These profiles contain groups of devices (i.e. a phone, 2 laptops and a tv). The problem is, the max number of profiles that we can create at a time is 5. I have a feeling that the users who try to make 6 or more profiles will get frustrated if they reach the 5th profile only to find out they can't create anymore. This means they'll have to go back and regroup their devices to fit 5 profiles maximum. Is there any way I can relay that information to the user at the first step (screenshot shown below) so that they know the max number of profiles is 5?

[image]

Comment: _Why_ is there a limit on the number of profiles?

Answer (score 5):

You can show the available spots. This works best in a grid:

[image]

Other ways are possible, like horizontal scrolling if space is an issue, although that could be a challenge to design since not all spots are visible at once.

Show also the numbers for quantity and quota so people have more handles to know what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to **use plain language in place of the number** showing the number of profiles.  So instead of "Kid's profiles (2)", I would simply use "Kid's profiles (2 of 5)", and then **add a popup** when someone tries to add another profile but the max has been reached.  **Don't disable or hide the `Add` button** as that isn't accessible and can be frustrating to anyone that doesn't realise why they can't add.

Answer (score 1):

1.Disable the add button and show the added quantity and addable quantity, show the reason in hover tips

[image]

2.Hide the add button when the maximum number of addables is reached

[image]

Comment: Displaying information via hover isn't very accessible - not everyone uses a mouse to interact with apps.

Comment: Disable and quantity have already completed the prompt, the hover is just an intentional redundant design